# Align curve control point tilt with snapping target

Tags: bezier-curves

Is it possible to extrude control points of a curve along the surface of an object and have the tilt of each point automatically align with the normal of the face that it snaps to?

EDIT
I want the beveled shaped to automatically stay normal to the surface I am snapping to without having to manually adjust the tilt for each control point. It starts off right.
[image]

But then the tilt changes dynamically as each control point is extruded.
[image]

EDIT, still have not found a solution. I have tried using sverchok to make a node tree that would find that closest face of the target object and adjust each control point tilt on the curve to make it normal to the surface but I could not get it to work.

Comment: Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/50777/how-to-make-a-curve-segment-perpendicular-to-a-face/50779#50779

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if this is what you're looking for but you may enable the ***project individual elements on the surface of other objects*** option (with the **snapping tool (Face)** enabled also).
[image]

Comment: This option does not accomplish what I am looking for. You can see in your example clip that the tilt on all the control points changes as you add new points. I am looking for something that would keep the normal of the extruded shape perpendicular to the face that the curve is snapping to.